# Python: Get multiple return values and provide multiple arguments in executor.map of concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor()

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, threadpoolexecutor

I am quite new to Python multiprocessing concept.
I am trying to call function `magicFunction` which has multiple argument out of which first is iterable while all other are non-iterable. Also, it returns multiple value, let us say `x, y, z`

I am trying to figure out how to use `executor` here. Here is my approach, which is obviously wrong.

```
def magicFunction(webElem, uid_list, ignoreTagsList):
    ..
    ..
    return x,y,z

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    for webElem, x_val, y_val, z_val in zip(webElem_list, executor.map(magicFunction, webElem_list, uid_list, ignoreTagsList)):
    ..
    ..
    print("Values:", x_val, y_val, z_val)
```

Can someone suggest correct way to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a class:

```
class FunctionReturn:
    x = 0
    y = 0
    z = 0

def myFunction():
    output = FunctionReturn()
    output.x = 1
    output.y = 2
    output.z = 3
    return output

data = myFunction()
print(data.x , data.y , data.z)
```

This will print 1 2 3

Answer (score 1):

```
import concurrent.futures

## This works list of numbers
def square(number):
    return number ** 2, True

number = [1,2,3,4,5]
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    future = [executor.submit(square, i) for i in number]
    print (future)
    return_value = [i.result() for i in future]
    print (return_value)
    d = {k:v for k, v in return_value} ##if you want in dictionary
    for k, v in return_value:  ##if want iterate and get the values
        print (k, v)




import concurrent.futures

def square(number):
    return number ** 2, True

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    future = executor.submit(square, 5)
    return_value, bool_value  = future.result()
    print(return_value, bool_value)

o/p: 25 True
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.